# Как загрузить несколько текстур в разные координаты на один объект three.js?

Tags: three.js

есть 3d модель машины( *.fbx), стоит на плоскости (PlaneBufferGeometry), у которой есть текстура (TARMAC2.jpg). нужно в javascript на объект PlaneBufferGeometry поместить тень от машины (shadow.jpg) и свет от фар (light.jpg).

освещение не дает реалистичной тени под машиной. Отрендерила тень отдельно. как положить тень под машину, текстуру света от фар и png блики на фары как в этом примере: https://renaultespace.littleworkshop.fr/
? спасибо за любую инфу!!!!
в js новичек

вот как это загружено сейчас с использованием lightMap. проблема: lm-текстура с тенью растягивается по всей поверхности. нужны наверное новые uv координаты, не представляю как их задать для lm.

```js
var groundGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 10000, 10000 );
    var groundMat = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("model/TARMAC2.jpg", function ( map ) {
    map.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    map.anisotropy = 10;
    map.repeat.set( 10, 10 );
    groundTexture = map;
    }  );
    var lm = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("model/shadow_copy514.jpg");
    var groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
                    {
    color: 0xdad8d5,
    lightMap: lm,
    map: groundMat
    });
    var uvs = groundGeo.attributes.uv.array;
    console.log(uvs);
    groundGeo.addAttribute( 'uv2', new THREE.BufferAttribute( uvs, 2 )     );
    var ground = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeo, groundMaterial);
    ground.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
    ground.position.y = -3;
    scene.add( ground );
```

Comment: Можно использовать `THREE.ShaderMaterial()`, передав ему через униформы три текстуры. Можно использовать какой-то из стандартных материалов со свойством `.lightmap`. Вариантов - масса. Можно задать этот вопрос на [форуме](https://discourse.threejs.org/) (англоязычный).

Comment: prisoner849 спасибо за ответ.

THREE.ShaderMaterial() для меня очень сложен, все что не пробовала пока не работает.

пробую .lightmap , но моя тень растягивается по размерам плоскости. так понимаю lightmap нужно задать еще один набор uvs, но не представляю как это сделать, может кто-то направит в поиске инфы...

Comment: про .lightMap можно посмотреть у любого материала - нужен второй набор uv координат. Так же можно попросить помощи на форуме - народ у нас там доброжелательный :) Ссылка на форум - в предыдущем комментарии.